# Python understanding recursive program

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am trying to understand the following program to find a number of the subset which forms a given sum from a given list.

```
def count_sets(arr, total):
    return rec(arr, total, len(arr)-1)


def rec(arr, total, i):
    print(arr, total, i)
    if total == 0:
        return 1
    if i < 0:
        return 0

    if arr[i] > total:
        return rec(arr, total, i-1)

    else:
        return rec(arr, total-arr[i], i-1) + rec(arr, total, i-1)

arr = [2,10,6,4]
print(count_sets(arr, 16))
```

the program works without any error, however, I am not able to find how it works.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) algorithm.   In [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) `rec(arr, total, i)`, it picks the last element `arr[i]` in rest array, and here are two main situations:

1. use `arr[i]`: `rec(arr, total-arr[i], i-1)`
2. not use `arr[i]`: `rec(arr, total, i-1)`, and when `arr[i] > total` of course you can only not use it.

and we must have terminate condition for `recursion`, that is:

1. [success] find the subarray equal to total: `if total == 0: return 1`
2. [failed] reach the head: `if i < 0: return 0`

Hope I make it clear, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: Nicely explained!

Comment: Thanks, forgive my poor english : ) @MagedSaeed